# I want to read the values from the lines in the input file and use them as the constructor parameters of the object

Tags: java, file

For example
Person Kevin Spacey 156 Man 23/07/1979 Single Yes//
I need to create a person object with name Kevin, last name Spacey, ID 156, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this use case I would use a CSV file, so I can make sure that also names containing a space can be read.

A line in the file would look like this:

> Kevin;Spacey;156;Man;23/07/1979;Single;Yes

This file can then be read line by line and converted into a person object.

```
public class App
{
    private static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File file = new File("file.csv");

        if (!file.canRead() || !file.isFile()) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        BufferedReader in = null;
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String row = null;
            while ((row = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] data = row.split(";");

                int id = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);
                String firstName = data[0];
                String lastName = data[1];

                //TODO read the remaining parameters

                persons.add(new Person(id, firstName, lastName));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class Person {
        private int id;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

        public Person(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
            // TODO add the remaining parameters 
            this.id = id;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, but he need to be sure the format of output from file is always the same, for example person is not simply kevin , without last name, or he does'not have a middle name, or any other missing field.

Comment: @TheGoldy This problem can occur with the specified formatting and with a CSV. Using a file without a delimiter makes the problem even more difficult to solve.

Comment: hmm but i appreciate you found time to write that lengthy code